# Which is better between webview_flutter vs flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been developed web view in flutter.I don't know clearly which is better
webview_flutter vs flutter_webview_plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) other than `webview_flutter` and `flutter_webview_plugin`. It's a Flutter plugin that allows you to add an inline webview, use a headless webview, and open an in-app browser window.

Currently, it's the most **advanced** and **feature-rich** WebView implementation you can find for Flutter.
You can check the official [inappwebview.dev](https://inappwebview.dev/) website for more details and documentation!

Also, starting from **version 6** (the current latest one is [6.0.0-beta.20](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.20)), it supports **Web** and **macOS platforms**!

Comment: do you know when will version 6 be available? I am debating whether I should use the official `webview_flutter` or `flutter_inappwebview` One advantage for sure is the support of All platforms, instead of handing Mobile and Web differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In `webview_flutter`, “Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.” [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/webview_flutter/example/lib/main.dart#L36)

In `flutter_webview_plugin`, “The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs ...” [source](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

Also, there is [keyboard issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19718) so if you intend to use this for OAuth or something, stick with `flutter_webview_plugin`

[Read more on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/b7pfhb/webview_flutter_vs_flutter_webview_plugin/)

Comment: The keyboard issue is now fixed, but there is an additional reason to use flutter_webview_plugin over webview_flutter: webview_flutter requires at least Android SDK version 20. flutter_webview_plugin also works with older Android versions.

Comment: Does webview_flutter support authentication?

Comment: @DeepakJoshi does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062671

Comment: This is flutter_webview_plugin, which is a community version. Anyways I found the solution with webview_flutter, we can use onWebViewCreated: (controller) { controller.load(url, headers); } and not use initial url. Thanks for the reply Doc

Answer (score 3):

The `webview_flutter` is developed by the flutter team and it is the official way to integrate webviews in flutter app.

The `flutter_webview_plugin` is developed by the flutter community and soon it is going to be merged into the official `webview_flutter`.

[image]

As the two plugins are being merged and after the merger the unofficial plugin is going to be deprecated. So it is safe and my personal opinion to use the official `webview_flutter` from now on.